# Failing to get exact value from params

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using ruby 1.9.3.  I have the field "name" and the value is "J & E Mechanical Contractors Inc.", after submit the form, I got the following statement in controller.

```
Started POST "/pages/new?name=J%20&%20E%20Mechanical%20Contractors%20Inc." for
127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-15 13:59:08 +0530

Processing by PageController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"name"=>"J ", " E Mechanical Contractors Inc."=>nil}
```

Here I got name as "J", but expected result is "J & E Mechanical Contractors Inc."
Any suggestion.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request contains an unescaped ampersand character:

```
"/pages/new?name=J%20 & %20E%20Mechanical%20Contractors%20Inc."
```

That needs to be escaped,otherwise the web server treats it as a parameter separator.

Are you building up this post request manually?  If so, you need to URL Encode the parameters before issuing the request.

Comment: Do you know any URL Encode method from client side using Jquery ?

Comment: javascript has an encodeURI method: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp